# tmux sets start-directory for a new split window, and the directory may not exist, how to create it and cd?

Tags: tmux

I often have two panes on a tmux window, left pane to view source code, and right pane to `cmake .. && make`. I want to change to the source code directory quickly and `mkdir build && cd build` on right pane, but the build directory may not exist, if so, create and cd **build** directory if non-exist ? how to do this using tmux inner command or other advanced way ?

the following is my temporary and coarse approach, but It's not correct.

`bind o kill-pane \; split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}/build'`

Answer (score 1):

`send-keys` is the magic.

```
bind o kill-pane \; split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}' \;\
  send-keys -l 'cmd build' \; send-keys 'C-m' 'C-l'
```

`send-keys -l` stands for literal.
`C-m` to enter.
`C-l` to clear the screen.
P.S. `cmd build` is my own custom command works the same as `mkdir build && cd build`.